# Split a NumPy array into subarrays according to the values (sorted in ascending order) of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have two NumPy arrays

```
x = [[5, 2, 8],
     [4, 9, 1],
     [7, 8, 9],
     [1, 3, 5],
     [1, 2, 3],
     [1, 2, 4]]
y = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2]
```

I want to efficiently split the array `x` into sub-arrays according to the values in `y`.

My desired outputs would be

```
z_0 = [[5, 2, 8],
       [4, 9, 1]]
z_1 = [[7, 8, 9],
       [1, 3, 5],
       [1, 2, 3]]
z_2 = [[1, 2, 4]]
```

Assuming that `y` starts with zero and is sorted in ascending order, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Note: This question is the sorted version of this question:
[Split a NumPy array into subarrays according to the values (not sorted, but grouped) of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66708855/split-a-numpy-array-into-subarrays-according-to-the-values-not-sorted-but-grou)

Comment: Those aren't numpy arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `y` is grouped (doesn't have to be sorted), you can use [`diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) to get the split points:

```
indices = np.flatnonzero(np.diff(y)) + 1
```

You can pass those directly to [`np.split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html):

```
z = np.split(x, indices, axis=0)
```

If you want to know the labels too:

```
labels = y[np.r_[0, indices]]
```