# Split a NumPy array into subarrays according to the values (not sorted, but grouped) of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have two NumPy arrays

```
x = [[1, 2, 8],
     [2, 9, 1],
     [3, 8, 9],
     [4, 3, 5],
     [5, 2, 3],
     [6, 4, 7],
     [7, 2, 3],
     [8, 2, 2],
     [9, 5, 3],
     [10, 2, 3],
     [11, 2, 4]]
y = [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0]
```

Note:
(values in `x` are not sorted in any way. I chose this example to better illustrate the example)
(These are just two examples of `x` and `y`. values of `x` and `y` can be arbitrarily many different numbers and `y` can have arbitrarily different numbers, but there are always as many values in `x` as there are in `y`)

I want to efficiently split the array `x` into sub-arrays according to the values in `y`.

My desired outputs would be

```
z_0 = [[1, 2, 8],
       [2, 9, 1],
       [4, 3, 5],
       [10, 2, 3],
       [11, 2, 4]]
z_1 = [[3, 8, 9],
       [5, 2, 3],
       [6, 4, 7],]
z_2 = [[7, 2, 3],
       [8, 2, 2],
       [9, 5, 3]]
```

Assuming that `y` starts with zero and is not sorted but grouped, what is the most efficient way to do this?

Note: This question is the unsorted version of this question:
[Split a NumPy array into subarrays according to the values (sorted in ascending order) of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66680514/split-a-numpy-array-into-subarrays-according-to-the-values-sorted-in-ascending)

Comment: Can you say in words how the desired output relates to the sequnce of numbers in `y`?

Comment: Imagine that `x` is a point-cloud and `y` is the label of each point in `x` according to a clustering algorithm. `z` would be all the clustered sub-point-clouds of the original point cloud `x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is to build up a list of filter indexes for each `y` value and then simply select those elements of `x`. For example:

```py
z_0 = x[[i for i, v in enumerate(y) if v == 0]]
z_1 = x[[i for i, v in enumerate(y) if v == 1]]
z_2 = x[[i for i, v in enumerate(y) if v == 2]]
```

Output

```py
array([[ 1,  2,  8],
       [ 2,  9,  1],
       [ 4,  3,  5],
       [10,  2,  3],
       [11,  2,  4]])
array([[3, 8, 9],
       [5, 2, 3],
       [6, 4, 7]])
array([[7, 2, 3],
       [8, 2, 2],
       [9, 5, 3]])
```

If you want to be more generic and support different sets of numbers in `y`, you could use a comprehension to produce a list of arrays e.g.

```py
z = [x[[i for i, v in enumerate(y) if v == m]] for m in set(y)]
```

Output:

```py
[array([[ 1,  2,  8],
       [ 2,  9,  1],
       [ 4,  3,  5],
       [10,  2,  3],
       [11,  2,  4]]),
 array([[3, 8, 9],
       [5, 2, 3],
       [6, 4, 7]]),
 array([[7, 2, 3],
       [8, 2, 2],
       [9, 5, 3]])]
```

If `y` is also an `np.array` *and the same length as x* you can simplify this to use boolean indexing:

```py
z = [x[y==m] for m in set(y)]
```

Output is the same as above.

Comment: I should have added that 'y' can contain arbitrarily many different values. They don't have to be limited to two

Comment: So what would be your expected output if there were 20 different values in y? 20 different variables? Or a list with 20 entries?

Comment: I also should have added that there are as many 3-dimensional values in `x` as values in `y`

Comment: @danielhe see my edit, that may be more useful

Answer (score 1):

Just use list comprehension and boolean indexing

```
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array(y)

z = [x[y == i] for i in range(y.max() + 1)]

z
Out[]: 
[array([[ 1,  2,  8],
        [ 2,  9,  1],
        [ 4,  3,  5],
        [10,  2,  3],
        [11,  2,  4]]),
 array([[3, 8, 9],
        [5, 2, 3],
        [6, 4, 7]]),
 array([[7, 2, 3],
        [8, 2, 2],
        [9, 5, 3]])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation.

```
from operator import itemgetter
label = itemgetter(1)
```

Associate the implied information with the label ... `(index,label)`

```
y1 = [thing for thing in enumerate(y)]
```

Sort on the label

```
y1.sort(key=label)
```

Group by label and construct the results

```
import itertools
d = {}
for key,group in itertools.groupby(y1,label):
    d[f'z{key}'] = [x[i] for i,k in group]
```

---

Pandas solution:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> >>> df = pd.DataFrame({'points':[thing for thing in x],'cat':y})
>>> z = df.groupby('cat').agg(list)
>>> z       
                                                points
cat
0    [[1, 2, 8], [2, 9, 1], [4, 3, 5], [10, 2, 3], ...
1                    [[3, 8, 9], [5, 2, 3], [6, 4, 7]]
2                    [[7, 2, 3], [8, 2, 2], [9, 5, 3]]
```